# sending one object from list of objects

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, windows-store

In my main page there is 6 buttons

I use this code to send chosen buttons to my itemDetails Page

```
    private void Click_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetails));

    }
```

when user click one button, itemDetails Page must load specific information from switch statement

```
            protected void LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
        switch ("Click_Button")
        {
            case "btnAbout":

                aboutUs();

                break;
        }
    }

    private void aboutUs()
    {
        this.pageTitle.Text = "About us";
    }
```

it doesn't crash but my pageTitle still empty.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I don't think you understand the switch statement. It makes no sense when you switch on a hard coded string "Click_Button". Review : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

pass the button as parameter

```
Button btn = sender as Button;
Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetails), btn );
```

in your item details, do as below

```
private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn= e.NavigationParameter as Button;

   switch (btn.Name)
    {
        case "btnAbout":

        aboutUs();

        break;
    }

}
```

[Quickstart: Navigating between pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The switch is incorrect. You must have:

```
   switch (((Button)sender).Name)
    {
        case "btnAbout":

        aboutUs();

        break;
    }
```